# Adding underline placeholders to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a view that is used as a view that the user verifies a code sent to him by SMS in order to log in (6 digit code).

So I'm trying to create a `UITextField` for 6 digits only, and I want it to have an underline placeholder for each digit. Like this:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: When I implemented a similar feature I used a label for the character and a view for the underline for each letter/number. I then used a horizontal stackview to space them out equally.

Comment: @Scriptable Without a `UITextField`?

Comment: I had an off-screen, hidden textfield yeah.

Comment: @Krunal I couldn't really understand what you mean. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Scriptable Can you please explain a bit more about how you've done it?

Comment: this question is more than likely too broad for SO. I have told you how I would do it. there isn't much more to explain. Have a hidden/off screen textfield and use this as the first responder. as a user types or removes characters then update the display labels with whats in the textfield. using a textfield as the first responder stops you having to move between each letter in the display

Answer (score 2):

You can use the textField delegate protocol function `shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange` to modify the string as typing occurs.

0) Make sure the textfield is the one you are looking for

1) Get the selected text range and obtain a copy of the current text in the text field, otherwise fall through

2) With those variables, get the current index (Int) and the currentStringIndex (String.Index)

3) Determine if the replacement string is a delete ("") or an actual character

4) Delete the Previous Character

4.1 - Make sure current index isn't the start, and set the previous position and previous range

4.2 - Remove the previous character and replace with an '_' character

4.3 - Set the cursor position to the previous position

5) Add the character

5.1 - Make sure the current index at the max character index, and set the current position, current range, and next position

5.2 - Remove the current character and replace with the new character

5.3 - Set the cursor position the the next position

6) Return false since you've already modified the string

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // 0) Check and make sure textfield is the code textfield
    switch textField {
    case codeTextField:       
        // 1) Set the current selected range and the current text
        guard
            let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange,
            var text = textField.text
        else {
            return false
        }

        // 2) Set the current Index and String Index
        let currentIndex = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        let currentStringIndex = text.index((text.startIndex), offsetBy: currentIndex)

        // 3) Check if new character or delete character
        if string == "" {

            // 4.1) Make sure current index isn't the start, and set the previous position and previous range
            guard
                currentIndex > 0,
                let previousPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentIndex-1),
                let previousRange = textField.textRange(from: previousPosition, to: previousPosition)
            else {
                return false
            }

            // 4.2) Remove the previous character and replace with an '_' character
            text.remove(at: text.index(before: currentStringIndex))
            textField.text = text
            textField.replace(previousRange, withText: "_")

            // 4.3) Set the cursor position to the previous position
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: previousPosition, to: previousPosition)

        } else {
            // 5.1) Add a new character
            guard
                currentIndex < 6,
                let currentPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentIndex),
                let currentRange = textField.textRange(from: currentPosition, to: currentPosition),
                let nextPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: currentIndex+1)
            else {
                return false
            }

            // 5.2) Remove the current character and replace with the new character
            text.remove(at: currentStringIndex)
            textField.text = text
            textField.replace(currentRange, withText: string)

            // 5.3) Set the cursor position the the next position
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: nextPosition, to: nextPosition)
        }

        // 6)
        return false

    default:
        return true
    }
}
```